# Is there any way to save toggleClass in Wordpress to save a Sidebar position?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, local-storage, save

This is the code I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".fa-caret-right").click(function(){
    jQuery('#cita-absolute').toggleClass("hide");
    jQuery('.fa-caret-right').toggleClass("rotate");
  });   
});
```

It's a click function with two changes, one hiding the bar and the other one positioning the icon on the side and rotating it to let users expand the Sidebar again.

I've tried similar answers using localStorage without success.

I'm open in case there is a better approach for this using .hide and .show, or anything else, instead of ToggleClass.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) *is* the correct approach. It would look something like:

```
jQuery(function() {      
  const STATE = {
    EXPANDED: 'expanded',
    HIDDEN: 'hidden'
  };
  
  let currentState = localStorage.getItem('state') || STATE.HIDDEN;
  
  const render = () => {
    jQuery('#cita-absolute').toggleClass("hide", currentState === STATE.HIDDEN);
    jQuery('.fa-caret-right').toggleClass("rotate", currentState === STATE.HIDDEN);
  };

  jQuery(".fa-caret-right").click(function() {
    currentState = currentState === STATE.HIDDEN ? STATE.EXPANDED : STATE.HIDDEN;
    
    localStorage.setItem('state', currentState);
    
    render();
  });
  
  render();
});
```